# filtering an ASP GridView works but breaks other features

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

working on an ASP.NET GridView.
It works fine, but its default filter colum is not the one I want.
So I added this line into Page_Load method :

```
 i_gvOption.Sort("idWsgProgramOption", SortDirection.Ascending);
```

It filters as expected, the edit displaying is still perfect ...
but then my update and insert command nolonger work.

GridView code can be simplified as follow:

```
  <asp:SqlDataSource ID="i_sdsGvOption" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ...%>"
        SelectCommand="spWsgProgramOptionSelectNom" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" 
        InsertCommand="spWsgProgramOptionInsert" InsertCommandType="StoredProcedure"
        UpdateCommand="spWsgProgramOptionUpdateNom" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure" 
        DeleteCommand="spWsgProgramOptionDelete" DeleteCommandType="StoredProcedure">

        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="nomWsgProgramOption" DefaultValue="(name)" Type="String"/>
        </InsertParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="i_up" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:GridView ID="i_gvOption" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="idWsgProgramOption"
                DataSourceID="i_sdsGvOption" AllowPaging="true"  EnableModelValidation="True" AllowSorting="true">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Image" CancelImageUrl="~/...gif"
                        CancelText="Annuler" EditImageUrl="~/...gif"
                        EditText="Update" HeaderText="M" ShowEditButton="True" UpdateImageUrl="~/...gif"
                        UpdateText="Save">
                    </asp:CommandField>


                     <!-- my displayed columns, not worth listing their code-->


                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Del">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="i_imgbtnDel" runat="server" 
                                CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete" ImageAlign="Middle" ImageUrl="~...gif"  />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>

            </asp:GridView>
```

Why does this sorting line cause the other features to stop working????

EDIT:
I have just noiced something.
If I add into the datasource a triggered method on the update event:

```
OnUpdating="i_sdsGvOption_Updating"

    protected void i_sdsGvOption_Updating(object sender, SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e) 
    {
var id = e.Command.Parameters["@idWsgProgramOption"].Value;
var nom = e.Command.Parameters["@nomWsgProgramOption"].Value;
}
```

If my OnLoad method does NOT include the sort instruction:
both id and nom variables have the expected value.

When I add the sort instruction into the OnLoad method, nom variable still has its value into i_sdsGvOption_Updating, but id returns null.

That still does not help me to answer this question, but I am sure it will help you to find the answer.

Comment: Describe "no longer works". Do they error? Do they run but not change any data? What is the result?

Comment: @ mason : Nothing happens when I click the corresponding delete/update button.
Hard to say for sure if the event is not triggered at all or if it somehow fails to complete. I'd rather suspect it s not triggered at all anymore if I had to bet.

Comment: what are the parameters for `spWsgProgramOptionUpdateNom`?